# Openswan stopped writing to /var/log/secure after log deletion

Tags: linux, ipsec, openswan

I deleted the log intentionally but it seems like Openswan is not creating a new one on it's own. I tried restarting the service or even creating an empty file. Nothing works. 
What can I do besides reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syslog daemon is responsible for `/var/log/secure`, not Openswan. HUP or restart the syslog daemon.

Comment: Where are the Openswan logs saved then?